# Error While installing Kubuntu 14.04 in Virtual machine

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, virtualization

Running Kubuntu 14.04 in Virtual machine Gives me an Error :- `Boot : could not found kernel image : vmlinuxz.efi` 
[image]

how can solve these ?